# GetDIBits Returns Zero after Many Iterations In Screen Capture function

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, getdibits

I am using this code to capture screen and cursor.

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.

#include <Windows.h>
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

HWND hwndDesktop = NULL;
bool flg;
CURSORINFO cursor;
ICONINFOEXW info;
BITMAP bmpCursor;
HDC hwindowDC, hwindowCompatibleDC;
HBITMAP hbwindow;
int height, width, srcheight, srcwidth;
Mat src;
BITMAPINFOHEADER  bi;
RECT windowsize;    

Mat hwnd2mat(HWND hwnd)
{
    src.create(height, width, CV_8UC4);

    int val = 0;
    // use the previously created device context with the bitmap
    HGDIOBJ hPrevBitmap = SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow);
    // copy from the window device context to the bitmap device context
    val = StretchBlt(hwindowCompatibleDC, 0, 0, width, height, hwindowDC, 0, 0, srcwidth, srcheight, SRCCOPY); //change SRCCOPY to NOTSRCCOPY for wacky colors !
    if (val <= 0) {
        DWORD error_ = GetLastError();
        cout << "error " << error_ << endl;
    }
    cursor = { sizeof(cursor) };
    ::GetCursorInfo(&cursor);
    if (cursor.flags == CURSOR_SHOWING and flg) {
        info = { sizeof(info) };
        ::GetIconInfoExW(cursor.hCursor, &info);
        const int x = cursor.ptScreenPos.x - windowsize.left - info.xHotspot;
        const int y = cursor.ptScreenPos.y - windowsize.top - info.yHotspot;
        bmpCursor = { 0 };
        val = ::GetObject(info.hbmColor, sizeof(bmpCursor), &bmpCursor);
        val = ::DrawIconEx(hwindowCompatibleDC, x, y, cursor.hCursor, bmpCursor.bmWidth, bmpCursor.bmHeight,
            0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);
        if (val <= 0) {
            DWORD error_ = GetLastError();
            cout << "error " << error_ << endl;
            flg = false;
        }
    }
    val = GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow, 0, height, src.data, (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);  //copy from hwindowCompatibleDC to hbwindow
    if (val <= 0) {
        DWORD error_ = GetLastError();
        cout << "error " << error_ << endl;
        GdiFlush();
        flg = false;
    }

    SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hPrevBitmap);

    return src;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    flg = true;
    hwndDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
    namedWindow("output", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    int key = 0;
    hwindowDC = GetDC(hwndDesktop);

    if (hwindowDC == NULL) {
        DWORD error_ = GetLastError();
        cout << "error " << error_ << endl;
    }

    hwindowCompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);
    if (hwindowCompatibleDC == NULL) {
        DWORD error_ = GetLastError();
        cout << "error " << error_ << endl;
    }
    SetStretchBltMode(hwindowCompatibleDC, COLORONCOLOR);

    GetClientRect(hwndDesktop, &windowsize);
    srcheight = windowsize.bottom;
    srcwidth = windowsize.right;
    height = windowsize.bottom / 1;  //change this to whatever size you want to resize to
    width = windowsize.right / 1;

    hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hwindowDC, width, height);
    if (hbwindow == NULL) {
        DWORD error_ = GetLastError();
        cout << "error " << error_ << endl;
    }
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/window/dd183402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    bi.biWidth = width;
    bi.biHeight = -height;  //this is the line that makes it draw upside down or not
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    while (key != 27)
    {
        Mat src = hwnd2mat(hwndDesktop);
        // you can do some image processing here
        imshow("output", src);
        key = waitKey(1); // you can change wait time
    }

}
```

The Screen Capture works perfectly , but always fails after screen capture of just more than 8 mins and 30 seconds. 
After 8 min and 30 seconds GetDIBits starts to return 0 .
I am running this on a 64bit machine with windows 10 professional ediiton. 
This Issue seems to not apear if i remove the cursor capturing code .

Comment: You're leaking the bitmaps returned by `GetIconInfoEx`.

Comment: try calling `GetLastError` to find out why its failing

Comment: I am calling `GetLastError` , which is also returning 0

Comment: [GetDIBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdibits) doesn't set the calling thread's last error code. As noted above, [GetIconInfoEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-geticoninfoexw) comes with a liability: *"`GetIconInfoEx` creates bitmaps for the `hbmMask` and `hbmCol` or members of `ICONINFOEX`. **The calling application must manage these bitmaps and delete them when they are no longer necessary**."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DeleteObject(info.hbmColor);
DeleteObject(info.hbmMask);
```

Adding these lines did the trick. 
Thanks to [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) and [IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable)

Comment: Don't delete the hcursor. It is not yours.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your own answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.